# Illustrator colours and export as PNG

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've just installed Illustrator on my PC and I don't why but the colors in Illustrator look "Dull" however when I export my project as PNG they look fine.

I am working with RGB colors. Also, I have checked it in Photoshop and it looks fine before and after export. So I guess the problem is with some configuration in my Illustrator but I can't find how to fix it.

I was spending all my morning checking the different posts about that in this forum and on the internet but I didn't have luck.

Does anyone know where is the problem? I really need to see the real colors on my screen before to export.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding, you're saying that the colors on your screen while working in illustrator don't look true to what is exported as a .png file, right? 
Check to see what your proof setup is like: on my mac, that's view > proof setup. If you're soft proofing in a different color profile (like Working CMYK, or Color Blindness) than the RGB you're trying to work in, it can create problems. You'll want to make sure you chose the color preset "Internet Standard RGB (sRGB)", which simulates Windows and Mac OS 10.6 and later.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled color management?

It sounds like the working ICC profile is causing you issues.

If you haven't already, go to Edit -> Assign Profile and select Don't Color Manage This Document.

Comment: Yes I do.    Assign Profile: Don't Color Manage this document

Comment: @Mostaza Are you properly exporting for web?

Comment: I am exporting for screen and yes the colours in the PNG are the true colours. At least they match with my Photoshop version. However, the problem is in Illustrator before to export as screen the colours looks "Dull"

Comment: Try press ctrl + Y.

I think your illustrator  file is set to CMYK

Comment: I am using RGB (I've double check it)

Answer (score 0):

If you fixed all possible settings mentioned here and you are still having issues, double check is the ai file you are working on accidently created in cmyk. It happens quite often, so you just create new file in rgb and paste your artwork there. Maybe you will need to convert all colors to rgb after you paste the artwork (go to Edit colors), just to be on the safe side.